# What is the average period of time for moderators to respond to a private message?

Tags: support, moderation, moderators, private-messaging

I received a moderator private message on May 18, 2018. I responded to this message by asking an explanation to all moderators on May 19, 2018.

So far I have had no response, and I wanted to know if there is an average duration within which moderators should respond to the user messages.

Comment: I'm tempted to say 6-8 weeks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"by asking an explanation to all moderators"*?

Comment: @MartinJames shouldn't it just be 6-8?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't got access to statistics on how long it takes for mods to reply to messages. Maybe Shog will be able to help us with that.

Firstly, you did not ask for an explanation.

In terms of my knowledge of being a moderator, we don't always reply. Generally when a message is sent to a user, it's not giving good news, it often comes with a warning or censure and may involve a suspension, depending on the issue. There's usually a detailed explanation. Unless the user requires clarity, there's often no need to add anything further.

People will reply in few typical ways to a mod message (this is an approximation).

- Asking for clarity
- Defensive
- Aggression
- Apologetic
- Excuses
- Pleas

If the  user is asking for clarity in a civil manner, and it may not be obvious what the message is referring to, it's reasonable to expect a reply.

If the user is defensive or aggressive, there's less chance of receiving a reply.

It the user is apologetic, there's often no need to reply, that will depend on the individual mod and the circumstances.

If the user makes excuses, "the cat ran across my keyboard X times and happened to create 3 sock puppet accounts that upvoted me" the mod may not reply. There's no point in debating it.

If the user pleas to have any restrictions taken off the account, there may be no reason to reply, just to say "No".

We only have the tools we have, and we cannot see cats running across keyboards, but we can intuit from the results whether or not it appears a cat has run across a keyboard, or yes indeed that person told someone to "@#$% off".

Mods are here as exception handlers. We're here to enforce the rules that have grown out of the community itself. We can elucidate and educate where possible, but we're not here to circumvent the rules or debate issues with people who's accounts have shown to be contravening the [ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public).

You can expect a reply from a mod when there's something the mod needs to tell you that you haven't already been told.

And it's wise to remember, we're human, while we strive to resolve all issues in a timely manner, sometimes that's difficult.

Comment: I have my doubts about the _"we're human"_ part.... (atleast for some mods)

Comment: @AndréKool [what are you trying to say?](https://xkcd.com/1530/) :)

Comment: It's late, I'm trying to make [a bad joke](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/robot-secretary-phone-business-concept-retro-style-pop-art-59722098.jpg)

Comment: @AndréKool It doesn't matter much.  The were mods are just as good as the human ones, (except on full-moon nights).